# Introducing another condition at the end of a question by or- clause

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure

If I want to introducing another condition at the end of a question by or-clause, is the following sentence correct? Are the punctuation correct?

> 1. Is it just due to some constraints or it has important benefits?

Context: Some one have adopted a decision. Suppose that there are only two possible conditions: (1) the decision was totally due to some constraints and has not any benefits, (2) the decision has some benefits and was not totally due to some constraints. I want to ask which one of these conditions holds.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Without more details, it's hard to say what you are looking for. Tell us what your question is in response to. Add what what said before you asked that question.

Comment: "Is it just due to some constraints, or _does it have_ important benefits?" The second clause is another question, so it needs to be phrased in question form.